# Skype dial out shortcut

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, skype, voip

I've created shortcut on desktop which looks like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" "/callto:echo123"
```

However, whenever I run the shortcut I have firefox open with Launch Application popup. If I press OK, it goess to loop. Skype will never launch. Firefox does not have Skype add-on installed.

I want the shortcut to use existing Skype instance and dial destination contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox should not be associated with callto:-links. Open the Windows Explorer and go to:
Tools Menu -> Folder Options -> Tab "File Types" and edit the callto:-entry.
Also check your Skype settings and make sure it is associated with callto:-links.